# Using Pug and SCSS with Angular (ng-model)

Tags: angularjs, sass, pug, ng-class

I'm trying to learn Angular simultaneously with Pug and SCSS, my current issue is with the `ng-class` concept. My code is as follows:

**HTML (In Pug)**

```
form
   input#theSearch(type='text' ng-model="theSearch")
   br
   span(ng-class ="{'test': isEven()}") Example Text
```

**SCSS**

```
.test {
    color:red;
    font-size:80px;
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
angular.module("root", [])
   .controller("index",["$scope",function($scope) {
     $scope.theSearch = 1;
     $scope.isEven = function () { return $scope.theSearch % 2 === 0; };
}]);
```

So, ideally this will react when the user inputs an even number and turn the `span` red as well as increasing the size. Currently, it does not change despite even inputs. I suspect this is some rookie syntax mistake but any guidance on the issue would be most appreciated.

Side Notes:
I'm in the CodePen environment. Pug is included, SCSS is included, Bootstrap is included, Angular 1.6.1, is being used. All of the html is contained in `main.container-fluid(ng-app="root")`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you getting any errors? the module you posted works fine https://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/KqwEJP.

Comment: can you share your pen?

Comment: Figured it out thanks to your codepen! Answer is posted below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to the codePen posted by karthick! My HTML was missing `ng-controller="index"` on the `form` element. Without the controller, the `$scope` does not know where to be applied (I believe). Thank you again to karthick!